# gnuplot - adjust size of key/legend

Tags: gnuplot

How do I adjust the size of the legend in gnuplot (4.6.0)? By this I mean the size of the lines and *not* just the font size. When I switched from the pdf to pdfcairo terminal the size suddenly jumped and caused the key to overlap the points of interest. (I needed cairo to enable unicode.)

An answer I have just invented is (e.g.):

```
set key font ",8"
set key spacing 0.5
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It looks like we were reading the docs at the same time -- and is there a better way?  not really, unless you consider `set key spacing 0.5 font ",8"` to be significantly better ...

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To adjust the length of the samples:

```
set key samplen X
```

(default is 4)

To adjust the vertical spacing of the samples:

```
set key spacing X
```

(default is 1.25)

and (for completeness), to adjust the fontsize:

```
set key font "<face>,<size>"
```

(default depends on the terminal)

And of course, all these can be combined into one line:

```
set key samplen 2 spacing .5 font ",8"
```

Note that you can also change the position of the key using `set key at <position>` or any one of the pre-defined positions (which I'll just defer to `help key` at this point)