# setting space between legend/pattern with the text in stacked bar-chart

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, legend

I have gnuplot data file:

```
CS  31.73   18.32   20.78   22.88   1.97    1.29    0.90    2.01
FL  43.27   29.45   15.64   6.55    1.64    1.27    2.18    0.00
HB  32.44   20.43   14.89   14.53   5.42    10.92   0.80    0.31
HD  28.53   7.27    29.53   20.33   9.18    0.93    2.04    1.44
MR  22.56   36.19   10.66   15.51   9.45    4.32    0.80    0.31
ZK  27.15   10.81   27.40   16.10   8.05    7.24    1.06    1.71
All 30.00   21.35   18.05   16.82   6.14    5.39    1.11    0.85
```

And my gnuplot Script:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set key invert reverse above
set boxwidth 0.8
set format y "%.0f%%"
set border 3 
set yrange [0:100]
set size 0.9 , 1.8

set label 1 "1092" at -0.3,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 2 "500" at 0.7,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 3 "1000" at 1.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 4 "500" at 2.8,103  font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 5 "1000" at 3.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 6 "500" at 4.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 7 "500" at 5.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 


set output 'aspect.eps'
plot 'a3b-aspect' \
    using($2):xtic(1)   t "pattern 1"  lc rgb "#006600"  lt -1 fs pattern 1, \
''  using($3)           t "pattern 2"  lc rgb "#006600"  lt -1 fs pattern 2, \
''  using($4)           t "pattern 3"  lc rgb "#330000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($5)           t "pattern 4" lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 4, \
''  using($6)           t "pattern 5"  lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 5, \
''  using($7)           t "pattern 6"   lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 6, \
''  using($8)           t "pattern 7"  lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 7, \
''  using($5)           t "pattern 3" lc rgb "#660000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($6)           t "pattern 3"   lc rgb "#990000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3
```

Output:
[image]

I have to delete some space between legend(patterns above) and text. Could we custom rectangle size on that? and also invert my legend order... the bottom patterns in bar chart should be the first legend.
  Thanks

Comment: I also find another solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834037/gnuplot-adjust-size-of-key-legend

but it is different case, because I do `key invert reverse above` on my case. so it can be use the solution there..

Comment: I find  we can exchange the legend and text   http://chartgnuplot.sourceforge.net/legend.html

but it is using perl. I dont know about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default justification of the legend key is `Right` which isn't appropriate when using `reverse` like you do: Set the `Left` option.

Optionally you can also increase or decrease the space reserved for the text with the `width` option.

To have to lower row appearing first, don't use the `invert` option.

So with the key settings

```
set key reverse above Left width 1
```

you get the result

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer @christoph .. how to make the legend to be square not rectangle?

Comment: If you want to have the pattern samples to be squared, you can use `samplen 0.4`, but that doesn't look good.