# adding space between x axis and xtics in gnuplot histogram

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

Currently I created graphs with small size. The spacing really important at this case. I want to add more vertical space between my `xticlabels` and x axis. 
I have tried to set the x bar with

```
set xtics offset 0,graph 0.05
```

my gnuplot output:
[image]

The data and gnuplot script still same with my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399102/setting-space-between-legend-pattern-with-the-text-in-stacked-bar-chart/24402698#24402698).

Comment: Don't want to sound unhelpful or rude, but try and look at the margins, specifically bmargin property. Try `help set margin`. You will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Also this link should be useful: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/margins.html

Comment: Thanks for answer @zahain Akhtra. I was looked at margins, there is lmargin, rmargin, tmargin and bmargin and we implemented with `set bmargin at screen 10` . but it is not what I mean. I have to add more space with my xtixs label with margin of my graphs. i.e my `cs` with my `0% line` in my graphs

Comment: I guess there is relation with xtics. But I can't find any clue from gnuplot help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

First add a little bit of `bmargin` by

```
set bmargin 3
```

Since you need to add vertical space between your `xticlabels` and `x-axis`, you need to adjust the Y-offset, which can be done by the following

```
set xtics offset 0,-1,0
```

You can play around with the values to suite your need.